# textutil convert PDF to txt producing garbled output

Tags: pdf, conversion, text

I am trying to convert PDF files to text files using `textutil`.  I don't if there are special types of PDFs that can and cannot be converted.  The files I am trying to convert are in a searchable format, which I assume is a minimum requirement.  When I convert the file, the text document is completed garbled output.  Here is my code:

```
textutil -convert txt example.pdf
```

Here are some of the first lines, in case that helps to identify where I am going wrong:

```
%PDF-1.3
%ƒÂÚÂÎßÛ†–ƒ∆
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
xÌõYè‹∏«ﬂı)8>2”„å,R%Ÿªõ¯ﬁxs9ôM‚<YÅ`„Ô‰W,J¢‘íF3”@^2Z›<ädˇ:(ˇl>òüçuπ´Í¶ñ¶nõº.⁄⁄         
4>~˘œ?Ã_ÕøÕ”W_≠˘Ù’·ﬂ◊OL.ò´øÂKI5ÖÀª∫*≥O_ÃÀk”‘aH|\1OØØù
±Ê˙'sqv0◊ˇ2oÆ√Vñ©˘÷Êmy2jæ»;P+Ú¢(*s˝ikó3>z¸ãõæ8;èè˙Î„·ê—z~=|  
¯D˝rËî)WÈå<˝¡ÒˇnÆﬂ/3¿’UnõÆ4~∫Á;Ú”µ≠J˙4‰JWùîgz8€]êªA@g¸≠kRŸ¯‹÷ùàëeÁÔπUŸÓ÷Ü´≤Œ
```

I'm guessing it has to do with some encoding feature -- not my area of expertise, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried your luck with poppler's pdftotext/html? Not every PDF can be converted that way. See if you can search for text in the PDF, if that doesn't work then you might have to resort to OCR

Comment: The lines that you show here is the PDF.

Comment: @frostschutz That alternative worked perfectly.  After install, I ran `pdftotext example.pdf` and it produced exactly what I needed.  Feel free to suggest in the answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to [TEXTUTIL(1) manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/textutil.1.html)  it seems **pdf** is not between formats managed by this utility:

`fmt is one of:  txt, html, rtf, rtfd, doc, docx, wordml, odt, or webarchive`

On Linux/Unix installing a scriptable product like [XPDF/pdftotext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext)  may be a valid solution like some comment already suggested.

For those on OS X it's possible extract text from PDF by a native OS X automator action  ( ..see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/155253/23825) or [last 4' of this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lgwAKKuU0s)) then consider that automator's workflow can be "scripted" via [CLI automator command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/automator.1.html)